# Which gulp package(s) will minify anything within a html file?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a project where I work in a html file. When running gulp, need to minify the html and inline scripts if any, and then copy and rename with the extension .php.

Which gulp packages are required for these tasks?

Right now I'm using:

```
gulp-htmlmin

gulp-rename
```

and it works, except that inline `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>` don't get minified.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see http://npm.taobao.org/package/gulp-minify-inline-scripts or https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-inline

Comment: They don't seem to work with `<script type="application/ld+json">` - Googles structured data blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have a try with [gulp-minify-inline-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-inline-json)